If $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and all $f_n$ are measurable, how can I redefine $f$ on a null set to make it measurable?
I am self-studying real analysis out of Folland, and I am confused at the beginning of his proof of the Dominated Convergence Theorem. It reads as follows, where all $f_n$ map from measure space $(X,M,\mu)$.

Dominated Convergence Theorem: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1$ such that (a) $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. and (b) there exists a nonnegative $g\in L^1$ such that $|f_n|\le g$ a.e. for all $n$. Then $f\in L^1$ and $\int f = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f_n$
Proof: $f$ is measurable (perhaps after redefinition on a null set) by Proposition 2.11 and 2.12, and since $|f|\le g$ a.e., we have $f\in L^1 \dots$

What I am confused on is how to show $f$ is $M$-measurable (upon possible redefinition on a null set). Once I know that, it is clear that $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Here are my attempts to show $f$ is $M$-measurable, as well as Propositions 2.11 and 2.12 Folland uses.

Proposition 2.11: The following implications are valid iff the measure $\mu$ is complete:

If $f$ is measurable and $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e., then $g$ is measurable.
If $f_n$ is measurable for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e., then $f$ is measurable.



Proposition 2.12 Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(X,\bar{M},\bar{\mu})$ be its completion. If $f$ is a $\bar{M}$-measurable function on $X$, there is a $M$-measurable function $g$ such that $f=g$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere.

Attempt 1
Let $N := \{x\in X : f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x) \text{ is false}\}$. Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e., we know $N$ is contained in a set $E\in M$ where $\mu(E)=0$. Because all $f_n$ are in $L^1$ they are $M$-measurable, and so for any Borel set $B$, $f_n^{-1}(B) \in M \subset \bar{M}$. Therefore, each $f_n$ is $\bar{M}$-measurable. We know $\bar{\mu}(E)=\mu(E) = 0$ by definition of $\bar{\mu}$, and so $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere; Proposition 2.12(2) then says $f$ is $\bar{M}$-measurable. How can I then change the values of $f$ on $N$ to make it $M$-measurable, as suggested by Folland?
Attempt 2
Consider $f_n\chi_{E^c}$. Since $E^c\in M$, $\chi_{E^c}$ is $M$-measurable, and therefore all $f_n\chi_{E^c}$ are $M$-measurable. Moreover, it is clear $f_n\chi_{E^c}\rightarrow f\chi_{E^c}$ everywhere, meaning that $f\chi_{E^c}$ is $M$-measurable. I see that $f = f\chi_{E^c}$ $\mu$-a.e., but I'm again not sure how to redefine $f$ so that it is $M$-measurable. I want to just set it equal to $0$ on $E$ so that $f=f\chi_{E^c}$ everywhere, but this could mess up the fact that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for $x\in E$ that are not in $N$.
Any advice you have would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Why would it matter if you mess up the fact that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for $x \in E \setminus N$?  You still have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for $x\notin E$, i.e. almost everywhere.

In addition to what Daniel comments, the integral of $f$ is unchanged when restricted to $E^c$. So the conclusions of the theorem are the same.

I do understand that redefining a function on a null set does not change its integral. However, I was only able to prove that the redefined version of f is integrable, not the original f. So, is the dominated convergence theorem tacitly assuming that, if needed, I have redefined f on a null set so that it is integrable in the first place?
